# How to overwrite into local directory from hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I am using cloudera and I run the query in hive

```
insert overwrite local directory '/home/cloudera/Documents/test' row 
format delimited fields terminated by ',' select * from stocks sort 
by close desc;
```

But I gives me the error which is

```
Copying data to local directory /home/cloudera/Documents/test
Failed with exception Unable to delete the existing destination 
directory: /home/cloudera/Documents/test
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
```

Comment: The error mentions that the directory can't be deleted. What permissions does the directory /home/cloudera/Documents/test have? Does the user executing the command have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: It has rwx permissions

Answer (score 2):

The user that executes the command needs to have write permissions on the parent directory, in this case /home/cloudera/Documents, to delete the whole directory and create a new one. Furthermore the user needs to have the write permission to delete all files currently present in the directory.

- Check which user is executing the command
- Make sure that the parent directory /home/cloudera/Documents has permission settings that allow the user to write
- Make sure that the user has write permission on all files inside /home/cloudera/Documents/test

To make sure that this should work you can:

- Become the user that is executing the command
- Navigate to /home/cloudera/Documents/test and delete all files
- Navigate to /home/cloudera/Documents and delete the directory "test"

If this works the query will work. If it doesn't you need to check which particular permission setting is messing with your plan.